# Bind variable Error while creating trigger on table

Tags: plsql

I am PL/SQL newbie. I am not able to create trigger getting bind variabale errors for all variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ddl_change_after_insert1 AFTER INSERT ON changeddl.stats$ddl_log
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_osuser varchar2(100);
    v_current_user varchar2(100);
    v_host varchar2(100);
    v_terminal varchar2(100);
    v_owner varchar2(30);
    v_ddl_date date;
    v_object_type varchar2(50);
    v_object_name varchar2(100);
    v_ddl_type varchar2(30);
    v_sql_txt varchar2(4000);
    v_mail_message varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    v_osuser := 'osuser = ' || :new.osuser;
    v_current_user := ',current_user = ' || :new.current_user;
    v_host := ',host = ' || :new.host;
    v_terminal := ',terminal = ' || :new.terminal;
    v_owner := ',owner = ' || :new.owner;
    v_ddl_date := sysdate;
    v_object_type := ',object_type ' || :new.object_type;
    v_object_name := ',object_name = ' || :new.object_name;
    v_ddl_type := ',ddl_type = ' || :new.ddl_type;
    v_sql_txt := ',sql_txt = ' || :new.sql_text;

    v_mail_message := 'osuser :' || v_osuser ||
                      ',current_user :' || v_current_user ||            
                      ',host :' || v_host ||                    
                      ',terminal :' || v_terminal ||
                      ',owner :' || v_owner ||
                      ',ddl_date :' || v_ddl_date ||
                      ',object_type :' || v_object_type ||
                      ',object_name :' || v_object_name ||
                      ',ddl_type :' || v_ddl_type ||
                      ',sql_txt :' || v_sql_txt;


    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''127.0.0.1''';
    UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'root@localhost',
            recipients => 'chandan@gmail.in',
               subject => 'Database Objects Modified',
               message => v_mail_message,
             mime_type => 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
             END;
/
```

Below are my base tables. please help me to come out of this problem

```
CREATE TABLE changeddl.stats$ddl_log (
  ddl_date date,
  OSUSER varchar2(100),
  CURRENT_USER varchar2(100),
  HOST varchar2(100),
  TERMINAL varchar2(100),
  owner varchar2(30),
  object_type varchar2(50),
  object_name varchar2(100),
  ddl_type varchar2(30),
  sql_txt varchar2(2000));
```

Please help me i am new to plsql..

Below is the main trigger which will insert data to `stats$ddl_log` table whenver ddl changes.

```
create or replace trigger ddlchange_trigger after ddl on database
declare
  sql_text ora_name_list_t;
  stmt VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
  n number;
begin
  if (ora_sysevent='TRUNCATE')
  then
    null;
  else
    n:=ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
    for i in 1..n
    loop
      stmt:=substr(stmt||sql_text(i),1,1000);
    end loop; 
    insert into changeddl.stats$ddl_log(ddl_date, osuser,current_user,host,terminal,owner,object_type,object_name,ddl_type,sql_txt)
    values(
      sysdate,
      sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER') ,
      sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') ,
      sys_context('USERENV','HOST') , 
      sys_context('USERENV','TERMINAL') ,
      ora_dict_obj_owner,
      ora_dict_obj_type,
      ora_dict_obj_name,
      ora_sysevent,
      stmt
    );
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: HI below error for all variables.

Comment: Errors for TRIGGER DDL_CHANGE_AFTER_INSERT1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
23/32    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.SQL_TEXT'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:NEW` and `:OLD` are pseudo columns.

**How to use them ?**

`:NEW.your_table_column`

**OR**

`:OLD.your_table_column`

In your trigger

```
v_sql_txt := ',sql_txt = ' || :new.sql_text;
```

instead, change above line to below. Your table column was `sql_txt` not `sql_text`

```
v_sql_txt := ',sql_txt = ' || :new.sql_txt;
```

**==Update==**

Concatenating `newline` into the string

```
'Hi' || chr(10) || 'good' || chr(10) || 'morning'
```

use pipeline `||` to concatenate two string.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I will change.

Comment: HI Sir, my output is coming like this i want to change it to new line

Comment: osuser :osuser = oracle,current_user :,current_user = SYS,host :,host = localhost.localdomain,terminal :,terminal = pts/2,owner :,owner = TESTDDL,ddl_date :31-MAY-15,object_type :,object_type TABLE,object_name :,object_name = EMP,ddl_type :,ddl_type = CREATE,sql_txt :,sql_txt = create table emp as select * from scott.emp

Comment: Please let me know how to display instead of commaa seperated i want it to be display in new line..

Comment: concate `chr(10)` in your string to put newline

Comment: i am newbie sir... please let me know how to concate.

Comment: but it is displayin osuser:osuser 2 times

Comment: HI Sir, I tried like this but its not coming as newline

Comment: v_mail_message := 'osuser :' || v_osuser || CHR(10) || 
                      ',current_user :' || v_current_user || CHR(10) ||            
                      ',host :' || v_host || CHR(10) ||                    
                      ',terminal :' || v_terminal || CHR(10) || 
                      ',owner :' || v_owner || CHR(10) || 
       ',ddl_date :' || v_ddl_date || CHR(10) || 
       ',object_type :' || v_object_type || CHR(10) || 
       ',object_name :' || v_object_name || CHR(10) || 
       ',ddl_type :' || v_ddl_type || CHR(10) || 
       ',sql_txt :' || v_sql_txt;

Comment: Hi Sir, Its not displayin newline.. please help me.

Comment: where are you getting output ? On `oracle server` or some web page. I see you are trying to send mail. I'm sure you are verifying your output on email sent.

Comment: You should post new question and write down your actual output and expected output.

Comment: Yes sir, I am verifying in email sent.

Comment: then.. probably try `<br/>` instead of `char(10)`. That's `html` line break tag.